# Accessing child element through parent class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I access child element's `innerHTML` which has no class nor ID through parent element with class in JavaScript?

It should return only `text` between `<b>` tags.

```
<div class="parent element">
  <h5>
    some other text<b>text</b>
  </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe `document.querySelector('.parent.element h5 b').textContent`

Comment: document.querySelector('.parent-class-name h5').innerText

Answer (score 5):

```js
var innerText=document.querySelector('.parent.element h5 b').innerText
console.log(innerText);
```

```html
<div class="parent element">
  <h5>
    some other text<b>text</b>
  </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and `textContent`:

```js
var txt = document.querySelector('.parent.element > h5 > b').textContent;
console.log(txt)
```

```html
<div class="parent element">
  <h5>
    some other text<b>text</b>
  </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with a CSS selector like `.parent.element h5 b`, which will find a `b` tag, inside a `h5` tag, inside an element with the classes `parent` and `element`.

Then you can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to grab text only, or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to grab both text and markup.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.parent.element h5 b').textContent);

// sample when using innerHTML grabbing the h5
console.log(document.querySelector('.parent.element h5').innerHTML);

// sample when using textContent grabbing the h5
console.log(document.querySelector('.parent.element h5').textContent);
```

```html
<div class="parent element">
  <h5>
    some other text<b>text</b>
  </h5>
</div>
```

---

A note when it comes to [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Description) vs [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText):

> Internet Explorer introduced `node.innerText`. The intention is similar to `node.textContent`
>   but with the following differences:
>
> - While `textContent` gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements, `innerText` does not.
> - `innerText` is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas `textContent` will.
> - As `innerText` is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow, whereas `textContent` will not.
> - Unlike `textContent`, altering `innerText` in Internet Explorer (up to version 11 inclusive) not only removes child nodes from the element,
>     but also permanently destroys all descendant text nodes (so it is
>     impossible to insert the nodes again into any other element or into
>     the same element anymore).